# How can I render a text to multiple filled polygons?

Tags: python, fonts, geometry, polygon

I'm need to extrude text to a 3D triangle mesh using trimesh, open3d, or something similar.

Since these libraries don't contain any font related functions, I want to obtain polygons that correspond to glyph outlines as polygons and extrude those.

I've tried using fontTools and ended at using its `RecordingPen` to capture the outlines of glyphs. My problem now is that those use curves and I need just straight line segment polylines. I looked through the pens provided in fontTools and didn't find one that could approximate the curves with line segments. I also don't really feel like implementing this conversion myself.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own implementation a fontTools pen that does what I need:

```
class PolygonsPen(BasePen):
    def __init__(self, tolerance=3):
        self._tolerance = tolerance
        self.polygons = []

    def _moveTo(self, pt):
        self.polygons.append([pt])

    def _lineTo(self, pt):
        self.polygons[-1].append(pt)

    def _closePath(self):
        if self.polygons[-1][0] == self.polygons[-1][-1]:
            self.polygons[-1].pop()

    def _curveToOne(self, pt1, pt2, pt3):
        pt0 = self._getCurrentPoint()
        self.polygons[-1].extend(
            self._flatten_bezier_segment(
                pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3,
                0, 1, pt0, pt3,
                self._tolerance
            )
        )
        self.polygons[-1].append(pt3)

    @staticmethod
    def _bezier_point(pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, t):
        t2 = t * t
        t3 = t2 * t
        mt = 1 - t
        mt2 = mt * mt
        mt3 = mt2 * mt
        x = mt3 * pt0[0] + 3 * t * mt2 * pt1[0] + 3 * t2 * mt * pt2[0] + t3 * pt3[0]
        y = mt3 * pt0[1] + 3 * t * mt2 * pt1[1] + 3 * t2 * mt * pt2[1] + t3 * pt3[1]
        return (x, y)

    @staticmethod
    def _point_to_line_distance(x0, x1, p):
        x0_x, x0_y = x0
        x1_x, x1_y = x1
        p_x, p_y = p

        v_x = x1_x - x0_x
        v_y = x1_y - x0_y

        t = ((p_x - x0_x) * v_x + (p_y - x0_y) * v_y) / (v_x ** 2 + v_y ** 2)
        t = max(0, min(t, 1))
        closest_x = x0_x + t * v_x
        closest_y = x0_y + t * v_y

        return math.sqrt((closest_x - p_x)**2 + (closest_y - p_y)**2)

    @staticmethod
    def _linspace(t0, t1, count):
        step = (t1 - t0) / (count + 1)
        return (t0 + step * i for i in range(1, count + 1))

    @classmethod
    def _flatten_bezier_segment(cls, pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, t0, t1, x0, x1, tolerance):
        split_count = 9
        points = [cls._bezier_point(pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, t) for t in cls._linspace(t0, t1, split_count)]
        max_error = max(cls._point_to_line_distance(x0, x1, point) for point in points)
        if max_error < tolerance:
            return []
        else:
            mid_point = points[split_count // 2]
            mid_t = (t0 + t1) / 2

            return (
                cls._flatten_bezier_segment(pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, t0, mid_t, x0, mid_point, tolerance) +
                [mid_point] +
                cls._flatten_bezier_segment(pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, mid_t, t1, mid_point, x1, tolerance)
            )
```